# Did Darth Vader ever operate a button on the devices on his belt or his chest?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

Did Darth Vader ever operate a button on the devices on his belt or his chest?
If Darth Vader has equipment like the one on the belt with him at all times, it has to be important somehow.
But I don't remember him ever using any of those buttons.

Comment: I always figured they were flush n’ fill controls for his robotic digestive system

Comment: If canon isn't an issue for an answer, you should add the **star-wars-legends** tag

Comment: Vader uses his chest buttons here: https://youtu.be/u3tC8TPh9oQ

Comment: In Legends, Antinnis Tremayne manages to hit a button to incapacitate Vader during a training exercise. Presumably, someone toggled the "incapacitate incredibly powerful sith" button back to the off position.

Answer (score 1):

From [this book dedicated to his armor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545312159), we learn that its automated but he can activate it manually if he desires it.

There is a [full explanation here](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2015/12/buttons-darth-vaders-suit-actually-really-caused-emperors-deformed-appearance/) if you want to know if it makes him weaker or not.

Comment: This is the starting point for an answer but without explaining further about whether or not he did use the buttons and diving into what the book says I'm not really sure if this is _currently_ an answer.

Comment: We learn that what exactly is automated?